# deploying zend framework application in mediatemple GS

Tags: zend-framework, web-applications

i am having trouble deploying my zend framework application to mediatemple GS hosting.

I uploaded my application folder to `~/domains` and renamed it to `mysite.net` folder. 
Inside it, i created a symbolic link `html` which points to `public` directory in zend framework application folder. But the application is not working so far. Generally, mediatemple points a `host` to `~/domains/host/html` path so my domain `mysite.net` should point to `~/domains/mysite.net/html`.
Am i doing something wrong or is there more to this ? I am getting a 403 error when trying to access mysite.net

---

**Update**: Following rewrite rules make the base url http://mysite.net loadable but controllers dont work now. accessing http://mysite.net/controller sends page not found error :S

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

---

**Update**: Its solved now. The trick is to add above `.htaccess` file to the application root folder and also keep the original `.htaccess` in public directory. Together they do wonders.

Comment: found a fix here http://www.ttech.it/en/article/2010/03/zend-framework-all-projects-files-on-document-root/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution myself:

create a `.htaccess` file in application root folder:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
```

Also keep the original `.htaccess` in the `/public` folder. I delete this at first which made things worse.